# Passing SqlParameter in webmethod asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a web service which will help to execute stored procedure. And that web method I am calling in my code to execute a stored procedure. This is my web method -

```
[WebMethod(Description = des_ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand)]
public DataTable ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand(string CommandName, CommandType cmdType, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

            try
            {
                 if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                 {
                     con.Open();
                 }

                 using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                 {
                     da.Fill(table);
                 }
            }
            catch
            {
                 throw;
            }
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

Now this is my code in my data access layer - when I am trying to call this web method, its throwing compile time error.

```
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Data.CommandType' to 'DAL.sqlDBHelper.CommandType' 

Error   3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]' to 'DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[]'
```

My code to call the webmethod -

```
sqlDBHelper.ODCdbHelper mysqlDBHelper = new sqlDBHelper.ODCdbHelper();

public Login GetUserRoles(string _Idsid)
{
    Login login = null;

    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@UserName", _Idsid)
    };
    //Lets get the list of all employees in a datataable

    using (DataTable table = mysqlDBHelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("GetUserRole", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters))
```

Can you please tell me someone, where I am wrong??

Thanks in advance
Gulrej

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[] parameters = new DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[]//Change Here        {
            SqlParameter("@UserName", _Idsid)
        };
        //Lets get the list of all employees in a datataable

        using (DataTable table = mysqlDBHelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("GetUserRole", DAL.sqlDBHelper.CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters))
```

Comment: Now I have a doubt, can we pass sqlparameter in a web method??

Comment: sqlDBHelper.ODCdbHelper mysqlDBHelper = new sqlDBHelper.ODCdbHelper();
it doesnt take sql parameter ...bcz mysqlDBHelper ias type of ODCdbHelper

Comment: Tried the above code, not working... DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: Does your DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter implements IDataParameter? If so, you can use like this.. `DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[] parameters = new DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[]        {
            new SqlParameter("@UserName", _Idsid)
        };`

Comment: Not working this also...Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to 'DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter'

Comment: public DataTable ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand(string CommandName, System.Data.CommandType cmdType, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] param) change yor function like this and try your old code you wriiten..

Answer (score 0):

I presume `DAL.sqlDBHelper.CommandType` will be an enumerator in your data access layer. 
And the expected parameter is `DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[]` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]`

So you might call the select function as

```
DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[] parameters = new DAL.sqlDBHelper.SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@UserName", _Idsid)
};

using (DataTable table = mysqlDBHelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("GetUserRole", DAL.sqlDBHelper.CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters))
```

Please check what is the command type defined for stored procedures in your DAL.